# Add text to blog post form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

[image]

In the screen shot above, I'm trying to add a text in blog post form.
Do i need to change blog.xsl? if yes which part i need to change?

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of SharePoint Designer.

1. Connect to your site through SPD
2. Open up your blog, and edit NewForm.aspx
3. In the markup find the buttons, and place your text content before it.